# How to avoid spending time in creating tmp table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization, sql-optimization

I have the following MYSQL query.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(analyzer_host.server) AS count,
    analyzer_host.server AS server
FROM
    analyzer_host,
    analyzer_url,
    analyzer_code
WHERE
    analyzer_host.server IS NOT NULL
        AND analyzer_host.server != ''
        AND analyzer_code.account_id = 33
        AND analyzer_code.id = analyzer_url.url_id
        AND analyzer_url.id = analyzer_host.url_id
GROUP BY analyzer_host.server;
```

I did some profiling on this query and this is stuck in "Copying to tmp table" . Is there a way I can avoid that. Also any pointers in what is causing the query to create tmp tables.

Comment: Why are you grouping by and counting the same field? If you want all records for each server just use COUNT(*)

Comment: Group by is needed as later I am calculating the percentage of each server in the application with that information.

Comment: Is an index created on `analyzer_host.server` column ? This index is crucial for MySql to perform `group by` optimization, read this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: Yes , but it is a part of a composite index with other columns as well.

Comment: Please stop using implicit syntax. THis is a SQL antipattern and it is something that you shoudl have stopped using more than 20 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
SELECT  COUNT(host.server) AS count, host.server AS server
    FROM  host
    JOIN  url  ON url.id  = host.url_id
    JOIN  code ON code.id =  url.url_id
    WHERE  host.server IS NOT NULL
      AND  host.server != ''
      AND  code.account_id = 33
    GROUP BY  host.server;
```

That gets rid of `analyzer_` clutter and use `JOIN...ON` syntax.

Second, it seems that the JOINs are not quite right -- is there both an `id` and a `url_id` in `url`?  Is the `url_id` different between `host` and `url`?

Does `code` have `PRIMARY KEY(account_id)`?  That is where the optimizer would *like* to start.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can see if it is doing any table scans.  If it is, then *that* is the problem, not the "tmp table".

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all three tables if you need further discussion.